# How can I test error messages on MVVMCross?

Tags: testing, message, mvvmcross

How can I test error messages on MVVMCross?

I'm using ReportError method found on this sample on a Portable Class Library project:
http://slodge.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/one-pattern-for-error-handling-in.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you actually looking to test?

If you are looking to unit test the 'hub' that listens for and republishes errors, then you should be able to do that easily - just create an nunit test and one or more mock subscribers - then you can test sending one or more messages.

If you are looking to test some of your services or view models to check that they correctly report errors, then create unit test for them with mocks which simulate the error conditions - in the test, Assert that the errors are correctly reported.

If you are looking to just manually trigger the ui as part of development, then either find some way to reliably trigger an error (e.g. providing an incorrect password or switching the phone to flight mode) or consider adding a debug ui to your app with buttons to trigger mock errors.

If you are looking for integration or acceptance level testing, then either write manual test steps to trigger errors - or consider automated solutions like Frank, Calabash, Telerik ui testing or the excellent Windows Phone Test Framework (http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2JkJfHZDd2g) - although I might be biased on the last one

---

As an update on the error reporting mechanism itself, I have now moved in some of my apps to the more general messenger plugin for this type of reporting. But other apps still use the old mechanism.